# FFT uncertainity in frequency

Tags: fft

Hello What would the uncertainty be in frequency vs amplitude graph for the frequency? the peak amplitude is the dominant frequency, what is the uncertainty of that frequency?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The frequency estimation uncertainty is inversely related to the shorter of the duration of the frequency event or the measurement data window, and to some estimate of the signal-to-noise ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your signal is not buried in noise, the ability to accurately measure the signal's dominant frequency depends on the type of the window used (in the FFT analysis) as well as its length (window length). So,
when we do an FFT on a signal, we end up with an array of `frequency bins` (phase information is not important for this discussion). 
Each frequency bin has a `bandwidth` defined as

```
bin_frequency_width = sampling rate / window length; (e.g 44100 / 2048 = 21,53)
```

We can see that the larger the window length we're using, the better the frequency resolution we can get.

Every windowing function (`rectangular, Blackman, Hann` etc) has a property called `equivalent noise bandwidth (B),` which is nothing more than the (band)width of the main lobe for that particular window (`in bins`). Windows having
a wide main lobe have poor frequency resolution and vice versa.

The `equivalent noise bandwidth` (B) for a rectangular window is `1` and is greater than 1 for all other windows. A value of 1 for B means that the main lobe is exactly 1 bin wide, so if a particular window has a value of 2 (for B),
its main lobe is 2 bins wide and so on.

```
max_frequency_resolution_error = (bin_frequency_width * B)/2
```

Note that while using a rectangular window (no window at all) seems to be your best option for obtaining the best frequency estimates, this is not always the case. Due to the fact that a rectangular window also produces a lot of spectral leakage, you might not be able to discern close-by frequency components. Also, the noise floor will be relatively high, which is yet another thing to consider.

Note that windows that have a narrow main lobe (good frequency resolution) are not good for accurate amplitude estimates. Flat top windows are the best for amplitude estimates but since their tops tend to be wide, they're poor
for frequency estimates.